# Keeping Track of Clients connect to Twisted PB Server

Tags: python, twisted, perspective-broker

I am writing some backup software using Twisted PB to get information to and from the server and it is all working very nicely.

What I would like to be able to do is keep track of which clients are connected to the server. I have managed to get the IP address of the connection logged when the client connects. Initially the Clients get access to a pb.Root object which just has one method, this method returns another object that gives access to stored data.

What I would like to do is update the connection details for the connected client to include some information that is sent in the call sent to the server.

Here is my code for the client logging

```
class RKRServerFactory(pb.PBServerFactory):

    clientsConnected = {}

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        """
        Return a Broker attached to the factory (as the service provider).
        """
        self.clientsConnected[addr.host] = None
        print self.clientsConnected
        proto = self.protocol(isClient=False, security=self.security)
        proto.factory = self
        proto.setNameForLocal("root", self.root.rootObject(proto))
        return proto
```

Here is the code for the initial connect method

```
def __init__(self):
    self.hostid = None
    self.storage = None
    self.databasepath = None

def remote_connect(self, hostid):
    self.hostid = hostid
    self.databasepath = os.path.join(os.path.join("/media/098974ed-f717-4dd4-8306-7c4863e87e67/rkr_server_storage", hostid))
    try:
        self.__initDatabase(self.databasepath)
    except IOError, e:
        return defer.fail(e)
    self.storage = RKRStorage(self)
    return defer.succeed(self.storage)
```

I am unsure how to get the client disconnect to be logged too. If anyone can help I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Twisted triggers the `clientConnectionLost()` event/method.

Example:

```
def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
    print 'Lost connection.  Reason:', reason
```

See: https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.1.0/core/howto/clients.html for examples and details.

Comment: I am trying to keep track of the connected clients on the server end of the PB connection, and I cant see a way of doing it

Comment: This is the way you do it. Creates methods for ``clientConnectMade`` and ``clientConnectionLost`` and keep a mapping somewhere of your connected clients.